# Selenium, waiting for element to appear, but text isn't available

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

On the following website : https://hepa.hu/hirek
[I'm waiting for this piece to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdaxf.png).
This is javascript generated, so I have taken to using Selenium in C#. I've written the following code, to wait for the element to appear:

```
driver.Url = "https://hepa.hu/hirek";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IWebElement firstResult = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//body/app-root/app-base/section/div/app-news/section/div[2]/div[4]/a[1]/app-news-card/div/div[2]/h3")));
```

(The Xpath was copied from the node itself)
The code works, as far as it really waits for the element to appear, but when I try to access the text inside (firstResult.Text), it just gives "", instead of the actual text inside.
[The text is inside the h3 tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NMDu.png). I have also been using HtmlAgilityPack, and there, when I found the node I needed, I could access the text inside with the InnerHtml tag, but as far as I can see, there is no such thing in Selenium.

Another thing to note, when I check the PageSource attribute of the driver, I can see the h3 tag inside, and I can also see the needed text inside.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load the page, scroll down 1000 pixels, and then use the xpath below. Once you scroll down, the element should be there. If you need to, throw in a wait.

You can call this like:

```
        WaitForElemDisp_byXPath("//div[@class='news-cards']/a[1]//div[@class='news-card-text']/h3");

        public static bool WaitForElemDisp_byXPath(string path)
    {
        var result = true;
        try { _wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(path)).Displayed); }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(path); }
        catch (NoSuchElementException) { WaitForElementDisplayed_byXPath(path); }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { result = false; }
        return result;
    }
```

This will get you the text for the h3.

```
var test =  driver.findelement(by.Xpath("//div[@class='news-cards']/a[1]//div[@class='news-card-text']/h3")).Text;
```

Comment: This code finds the node as well, but it still doesn't give me the text inside for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a VERY round-about way to solve this. A few nodes up from the text I want to get, is an  tag, with a href link to an article, which obviously also has the text I need. So what I did, is I found the  node, got the href attribute, went to that site, found the tag I needed, and there, for some reason, getText() works.
Still, I don't want to close this thread, as the original question still stands, how can I get the text from the original node? I'm very interested as to why it didn't work.

Comment: I just ran a simple test and that code returns the expected text. What does your code look like? When you run it through debug does it work?

Comment: ![This is how I call my function, which is very much like the one you wrote in your first comment.][https://imgur.com/UDU62TH]
![And this is how the code looks like,][https://imgur.com/tw7HxX8]
So I give the website, give the XPath, and the function returns with the Text of the node. However, it doesn't work with this site (for me).

Comment: Well, honestly, it really didn't work for me first. However, I tried it now, and it works. Funny that. Well thanks for the help, I'm really not sure why I couldn't get the text for some time, and why I could get it now.

Comment: ok glad it worked. Please make sure you accept the answer.